# Deny an access to shared memory from non-forked processes

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-memory

I need to create a shared memory segment which contains some secret data. I use `shmget` and `shmat` functions to access the segment with **0600** rights. I want to share this segment of memory with forked processes only. I tried to create another application which tried to access this segment and it was unsuccessful, so it looks like it's working as I want.

But when I run the application which created the segment again, it can access the segment. How is it possible? Is a good idea to store secret data into shared memory?

Answer (score 6):

You can [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) shared and anonymous memory region by providing `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flags in parent process. That memory will be accessible only to that process and its children. As memory segment is anonymous, no other processes will be able to refer to it, let alone access/map it:

```
void *shared_mem = mmap(NULL, n_bytes, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Parent process should create shared memory segment using `mmap()`. That memory segment is inherited by any child process created by `fork()`. Child process can simply use `shared_mem` pointer inherited from parent to refer to that memory segment:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    void *shared_mem = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // parent
        // use shared_mem here

    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        // use shared_mem here

    } else {
        // error
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but probably I did something wrong.. The first process immediately after its start creates a shared memory segment using `mmap` and value of the pointer is saved into shared memory accessed by `shmget` and `shmat`. Next process (forked from the first one) reads the "mmap" pointer, but when I try to access it, it leads to segfault :-/ The application probably calls `execve` after `fork` (I don't know the app deeply) and therefore I can not access the shared memory.

Comment: No, you don't have to use `shmget` and `shmat` at all. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I know, what are you trying to tell me, but in my case is the `main` function run for two times. It looks like that after `fork` is called `execve` which runs the same app with modified arguments. So in the new process I'm not able to read `shared_mem` variable. That's why I saved the pointer into shared memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, `execve` replaces process image with new one. According to [`man execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve): "All process attributes are preserved during an `execve()`, except the following: (...) Memory mappings are not preserved (`mmap(2)`)"

Answer (score 4):

The shared seg doesn't belong to a process, it belongs to a user. Effectively settings 0600 only allows that user for RW (and root), however any other process running as this user will have the same access.

Create a specific user, to be "used" (logged in) only for this purpose.

> Is it a good idea to have secret data in a shared memory segment?

Think of the segment as a file - maybe a bit less easy to access (need to know IPC) - except it will disappear when the system shuts down.

Is it a good idea to store secrets in a file? Maybe not if the data is clear text.

In a file or in a shared mem segment, data encryption would be an improvement.

See [this page](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) for detailed explanations on how you can control a shmem segment.

---

OTOH if what you need is only to have a process exchanges information with her children, see [processes piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping). In this case the secret data is stored within the processes heap/stack memory, and is more difficult to reach by external processes owned by the same user. But the user "owning" the process may also read a process memory (via a core dump for instance) and search for the secret data. Much less easier, but still possible.

Note that in this case, if the secret data is available in the parent process before `fork()` is performed, children will automatically inherit of it.

Again, anyway, think encryption.

Comment: generally, encryption would be fine.. but I have encrypted data at first (from a file) and the file is very big.. and there are multiple processes which want to read clean data.. so I wanted to decrypt the data into shared memory..